# Using LuaTeX to automate \textcite vs. \nptextcite from biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, luatex, apa-style

According to the [`biblatex-apa` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf) (section 4.1), APA dictates that citations inside parentheses should not contain extra parentheses. Therefore, it provides the command

> `\nptextcite[⟨prenote⟩][⟨postnote⟩]{⟨key⟩}⟨punctuation⟩`

which works like `\textcite`, but suppresses the parentheses.

This is all very good, unless you are converting your document from something else, e.g. markdown, where you cannot make a distinction similar to the one between `\textcite` and `\nptextcite`. So I was wondering if there is a way to automate this **using LuaTeX**? Can we define a command `\autotextcite` which expands to `\textcite` and `\nptextcite`, depending on the current parenthesis level?

To be usable in practice, it should preferably work the following way:

- It should remember the parenthesis level in the entire paragraph, not just the individual lines, so using the `process_input_buffer` callback to do a simple regex string replacement on a line-by-line basis wouldn’t work.
- The parenthesis level should be reset for each new paragraph so that forgetting a `)` somewhere in the text will not mess up the rest of the document.
- It should preferably not involve making the characters `(` and `)` active, for obvious reasons (it would destroy many other interfaces). Likewise, string replacing `(` and `)` by something like `(\directlua{parlevel=parlevel+1}` and `\directlua{parlevel=parlevel-1})`, respectively, will probably cause errors, too.

So what I hope for is something that works like this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}

@online{tex.sx,
    author={{egreg et al.}},
    year={2022},
    title={{TeX Stack Exchange}},
    url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\newcommand\autotextcite{%
    \ifinsideparentheses
        \nptextcite
    \else
        \textcite
    \fi
}


\begin{document}

This follows from \autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx}. % Should yield \textcite

(It also follows from \autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx}.) % Should yield \nptextcite

(It also follows from
\autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx} % Should yield \nptextcite
among other places.)

(It also follows from other resources. % Here we forget a ")"

But \autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx} is a good start. %Should yield \textcite

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the following would work? Add a `process_input_buffer` callback to create a Lua table with parentheses level changes with their character position (like `{0: 1, 27:0}` for the simple case of a line of length 28 surrounded by parentheses), then add a second callback to insert the correct cite command using the parentheses level table and the character position of the `\autotextcite` command, and reset the level counter on `\par` or empty line. Do you think that would fulfill the requirements?

Comment: @Marijn It sounds like it would, and perhaps that is the only way to do it. (My original hope was something like: Every time LuaTeX digests a token, test if it is a parenthesis, if yes, change a Lua variable measuring the parenthesis level counter. Then run Lua code inside `\autotextcite` checking the value of this variable and inserting the correct command accordingly. But as far as I know, LuaTeX still doesn’t have a token callback, so this might simply not be possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Lua to look at the list which is currently being build. In a paragraph this will normally be the current paragraph, while in a `\hbox` (or `\mbox` or similar) this will only look at the current hbox. Normally that should lead to the expected result:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{find_parens.lua}
-- From Marcel Krüger's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654261/80496

-- How to translate boolean results to TeX macros selecting the right arguments
local bool_to_token = {[false] = token.create'use_ii:nn', [true] = token.create'use_i:nn'}

-- The codepoints we have to look for
local left_paren = string.byte'('
local right_paren = string.byte')'

-- Some boilerplate to define an unexpandable command sequence from Lua
local id = luatexbase.new_luafunction'ifInParensTF'
token.set_lua('ifInParensTF', id, 'protected')
lua.get_functions_table()[id] = function()

  -- We want to look at the current list
  local head = tex.nest.top.head

  local level = 0
  -- and look at all unprocessed characters
  for _, char in node.traverse_char(head) do
    -- Track the nesting level
    if char == left_paren then
      level = level + 1
    elseif char == right_paren then
      if level > 0 then
        level = level - 1
      else
        -- Negative levels don't make sense, so we ignore the ) instead. Print a warning though to avoid surprises.
        luatexbase.module_warning('find_parens', '\z
          Unable to reliably determine if inside parentheses\n\z
          since the paragraphs contains an unmatched `)`.\n\z
          It will be ignored\z
        ')
      end
    end
  end
  -- Finally insert a macro which will select the first or second argument dependingon whether level > 0
  token.put_next(bool_to_token[level > 0])
end
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}

@online{tex.sx,
    author={{egreg et al.}},
    year={2022},
    title={{TeX Stack Exchange}},
    url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\directlua{require'find_parens'}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\NewDocumentCommand \autotextcite {}{%
  \ifInParensTF {%
    \nptextcite
  }{%
    \textcite
  }%
}


\begin{document}

This follows from \autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx}. % Should yield \textcite

(It also follows from \autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx}.) % Should yield \nptextcite

(It also follows from
\autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx} % Should yield \nptextcite
among other places.)

(It also follows from other resources. % Here we forget a ")"

But \autotextcite[front page]{tex.sx} is a good start. %Should yield \textcite

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It cannot really get any more perfect than this. Thanks for the solution! `:-)`

Comment: This is very nice - I will likely incorporate into the style in the next version, with suitable attribution to Mr Krüger. Will likely just override `\textcite` with this if using LuaTeX so it's automatic.

Comment: One question: Am I right that there is absolutely no way to do a similar trick in pdfTeX, i.e. accessing the list being built using TeX primitives?

Comment: @PLK You should probably also override `\parencite`, as I believe that APA dictates that such citations should not appear inside parentheses either.

Comment: @Gaussler - that sounds sensible - do you have a reference to APA 7th where it says anything about this specifically?

Comment: @Gaussler There is a way in pdfTeX, but it's very ugly.

Comment: @PLK “When text and a citation appear together in parentheses, use a semicolon to separate the citation from the text; do not use parentheses within parentheses.” ([APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/parenthetical-versus-narrative), n.d.).

Comment: Also, to cause less headache, the error message should probably contain the line number.

Comment: @Gaussler Which error message? Do you mean the unmatched paren warning? Should that be an error?

Comment: I meant the warning, not the error, sorry, my bad. But writing the line number would help the user.

Comment: @Gaussler I changed the warning a bit to both include the line number and look more like a normal LaTeX warning.

Comment: What did I say earlier? That it could not get any more perfect? Guess I was just proven wrong. It got more perfect. `:-)`

Comment: @MarcelKrüger - I would like to include this in the next release of the APA style - can I put your name in the "thanks to" section in the docs?

Comment: @PLK Feel free to do so :)

Comment: @PLK You should probably also include an interface to turn this behavior off for people who for some reason prefer to do it manually, or for legacy documents. Maybe you should also keep two commands `\nptextcite` and `\ptextcite` which enforce the two kinds of behaviour, for use in special cases (such as inside formulas). Just my thoughts (and you may have already been planning to do that)… `;-)`

Comment: \nptextcite will stay as it will be used inside parens in the automated solution. There shouldn't be a need to provide an option as \nptextcite will just work as it always has done if used anywhere. I generally don't add options to the APA style that turn off APA style elements as it's a headache to maintain and rather contrary to having a conformant style in the first place ... this is all implemented in git. If you want to try it, let me know.